# Burning Temperature of Copper Winding of Motor

Tags: motor, temperature, copper, winding

Burning Temperature of Copper Winding of Motor.

I Have 3 motors 150watt 0.75Amp 220V in Copper and Aluminum and Copper clad aluminum.

I want to know the maximum internal temperature of these motors so that I can apply a Thermal protection sensor to   avoid burning in   the future.

Can anyone tell me the approximate range of temperature of burning of winding wire.

Someone suggested  that  I     apply 45C temp sensor . I dont think   she is right.

Comment: You should be able to find this information in the motor's datasheet. Now you make assumptions on what is OK and what is not. That is never a good approach.

Comment: ^That information is not always available, especially for custom-built motors.

Answer (score 2):

How hot it's allowed to get depends on what it's insulated with.

Here's a handy guide from MWS Wire Industries, and **[here's the source.](http://www.mwswire.com/pdf_files/mws_tech_book/page2_3.pdf)**

If there's any question at all, err on the safe side and choose 100C.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, different types of magnet wire have different temperature classes of insulation.  They can be rated for anywhere between 90 C and 240 C.  You won't be able to tell what kind of insulation the magnet wire has by looking at it.  Your best bet is to look at the nameplate of the motor and look for an insulation class.  It might be an actual temperature like "180 C" or it could be a letter code like A, B, F or H.  A, B, F, and H are the most popular insulation classes and have rated temperatures of 105 C, 130 C, 155 C, and 180 C, respectively.  If you can determine the thermal class of the motor, then that will be the *minimum* that the magnet wire will be rated.

Even if you can figure out the rated temperature, that won't be the temperature that it burns up.  When wire manufacturers rate their wire, it is based off of an accelerated test where they apply a voltage in order heat up the wire.  They do this on 3 samples with 3 voltage and therefore 3 different temperatures.  They measure the time in hours, plot the 3 points and then extrapolate the 3 points to the 20,000 hour temperature.  That 20,000 hour temperature is used to rate the wire insulation.

But let's say the 20,000 hour temperature is 100 C.  You could raise the temperature to 110 C and the wire won't burn up right away ... it might still last 10,000 hours.  And you could raise it another 10 degrees to 120 C and it still won't burn up right away ... it might last 5,000 hours.  The wire will eventually fail at all these temperatures but the real question is when.  Raise the temperature high enough and it might fail in 2 hours or 1 hour or 10 seconds.

Assuming you can figure out a temperature, also keep in mind that motors don't heat up evenly.  You can get hotspots on the windings and you generally won't know where those hotspots are located.  Typically when you place a thermal protector or thermal sensor, you assume you are NOT on one of those hot spots and that your highest winding temperature is 5-10 C higher than what your sensor tells you.